# How to handle index out of bounds exception from a ByteBuffer

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer

```
package server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException  {
        ServerSocketChannel server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        server.configureBlocking(false);
        server.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(64000));
        Selector selector = Selector.open();
        server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
        while(server.isOpen()){
            selector.select();
            for(SelectionKey key : selector.selectedKeys()){
                if(key.isAcceptable()){
                    SocketChannel socket = server.accept();
                    socket.configureBlocking(false);
                    socket.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                }
                if(key.isReadable()){
                    SocketChannel socket = (SocketChannel)key.channel();
                    ByteBuffer socketbuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);
                    int read = socket.read(socketbuffer);
                    byte[]stringarray = socketbuffer.array();
                    socket.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(stringarray, 0, read));
                    System.out.print(new String(stringarray, 0, read));
                }
                selector.selectedKeys().remove(key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

everything is working really fine until I exit connection from client it gives this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(ByteBuffer.java:375)
at server.Server.main(Server.java:31)
```

Java Result: 1

when I get this error it closes all the sockets I connect with telnet

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you know what an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is? Do you know why it's thrown in your case?

Comment: program crashes when I close a telnet windows with command telnet localhost 64000. I want to fix the crash so it wont happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't checking the return value of socket.read() which will return -1 if the end of stream has been reached
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#read(java.nio.ByteBuffer)

try adding this

```
int read = socket.read(socketbuffer); //after here
if(read == -1){
    socket.close();
}else{ //the logic is weird after this so I just changed it
    socketbuffer.flip();
    System.out.print(new String(socketbuffer.array(), socketbuffer.position(), socketbuffer.limit()));
    socket.write(socketbuffer);
    socketbuffer.clear();

}
```

You should also check if a key is valid before using it.

Comment: Closing the channel is sufficient. It cancels the key. You don't need to do both. You must also `compact()` or `clear()` the `ByteBuffer` after the write.